# Text-Message Gateways & Incrementing Bash Variable Daily

Tags: bash, cron, cron-task

I have a bash script that is sending me a text daily, for 100 days.

```
#! /bin/bash
EMAIL="my-phone-gateway@address.net"
MESSAGE="message_content.txt"

mail $EMAIL < $MESSAGE
```

Using crontab, I can have the static $MESSAGE sent to me every day.

Other than hard-coding 100 days of texts ;)

How could I implement a variable counter such that I can have my texts say:

`"Today is Day #1"` on the first day, `"Today is Day #2"` on the second day, etc. ?

Note: The location of the requested text within the $MESSAGE file doesn't matter. Last line, first line, middle, etc.

**The only requirement for an answer here is that I know what day it is relative to the first, where the first day is the day the script was started.**

Of course, bonus awesome points for the cleanest, simplest, shortest solution :)

Answer (score 1):

For our nightly build systems, I wrote a C program that does the calculation (using local proprietary libraries that store dates as a number of days since a reference date).  Basically, given a (non-changing) reference date, it reports the number of days since the reference date.  So, the `cron` script would have a hard-wired first day in it, and the program would report the number of days since then.

The big advantage of this system is that the reference date doesn't change (very often), so the script doesn't change (very often), and there are no external files to store information in.

There probably are ways to achieve the same effect with standard Unix tools, but I've not sat down and worked out the portable solution.  I'd probably think it terms of using Perl.  (The C program only works up to 2999 CE; I left a note in the code for people to contact me about 50 years before it becomes a problem for the Y3K fix.  It is probably trivial.)

You could perhaps work in terms of Unix timestamps...

Create a script 'days_since 1234567890' which treats the number as the reference date, gets the current time stamp (from `date` with appropriate format specification; on Linux, `date '+%s'` would do that job, and it works on Mac OS X too), takes the difference and divides by 86,400 (the number of seconds in a day).

```
refdate=1234567890
bc <<EOF
scale=0
($(date '+%s') - $refdate) / 86400
EOF
```

An example:

```
$ timestamp 1234567890
1234567890 = Fri Feb 13 15:31:30 2009
$ timestamp
1330027280 = Thu Feb 23 12:01:20 2012
$ refdate=1234567890
$ bc <<EOF
> scale=0
> ($(date '+%s') - $refdate) / 86400
> EOF
1104
$
```

So, if the reference date was 13th Feb 2009, today is day 1104.  (The program `bc` is the calculator; its name has nothing to do with Anno Domini or Before Christ.  The program `timestamp` is another homebrew of mine that prints timestamps according to a format that can be specified; it is a specialized variant of `date` originally written in the days before `date` had the functionality, by which I mean in the early 1980s.)

---

In a Perl one-liner (assuming you specify the reference date in your script):

```
perl -e 'printf "%d\n", int((time - 1234567890)/ 86400)'
```

or:

```
days=$(perl -e 'printf "%d\n", int((time - 1234567890)/ 86400)')
```

Comment: This seems the most sensible way to do it (calculate days since day 0). Make sure you have GNU date for the `%s` specifier.

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer would be to export the current value to an external file, and read that back in again later.

So, for example, make a file called "CurrentDay.dat" that has the number 1 in it.

Then, in your bash script, read in the number and increment it.

e.g. your bash script could be:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Your stuff here.

DayCounter=$(<CurrentDay.dat)
#Use the value of DayCounter (i.e. $DayCounter) in your message.

DayCounter=$((DayCounter + 1))

echo $DayCounter > CurrentDay.dat
```

Of course, you may need to implement some additional checks to avoid something going wrong, but that should work as is.

Comment: Also, this is pretty crude - this will not increment the value of DayCounter if the computer is off, for example.

You could output the current value of system time instead, and within the script increment DayCounter by the number of days that have elapsed since the last message. That way, should the cronjob not run for whatever reason, your counter won't be behind for a day.

Comment: In bash, you should use $(< file) to read an entire file into a variable instead of the external cat command.

Comment: Thanks jordanm, I had not come across that before. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to accomplish this would be to store the date in a file, and read from that file each day. I would suggest storing the epoch time.

```
today=$(date +%s)
time_file="~/.first_time"
if [[ -f $time_file ]]; then
   f_time=$(< "$time_file")
else
   f_time=$today
   echo "$f_time" > "$time_file"
fi

printf 'This is day: %s\n' "$((($today - $f_time) / 60 / 60 / 24))"
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering that your script is running only once a day, something like this should work:

```
#!/bin/bash
EMAIL="my-phone-gateway@address.net"
MESSAGE="message_content.txt"
STFILE=/tmp/start.txt
start=0
[ -f $STFILE ] && start=$(<$STFILE)
start=$((start+1))
MESSAGE=${MESSAGE}$'\n'"Today is Day #${start}"
echo "$start" > $STFILE
mail $EMAIL < $MESSAGE
```